# Where is this site's scope formally documented?

Tags: support

I though I'd mention this site as an alternate answer to
https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1226/are-questions-about-vhf-antennas-off-topic-here and wanted to quote what is/isn't on-topic here, the sort of guidelines I sometimes see snippets of this when questions get flagged as off-topic.

But I couldn't find these guidelines listed when I click "Ask Question" here or a few other places — are they only the Area 51 site or what?

Answer (score 3):

https://ham.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

This is in the help center, and it can be updated by moderators as required. If you have a specific proposal to change, feel free to ask a new question here.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up finding this via a link *on* one of those flagged questions, actually one step removed at least for the on hold question I saw first. The fairly-generic "How do I ask a good question?" help page links to our site-specific "What topics can I ask about here?" page at https://ham.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic which contains the summary I was looking for.

Currently the main guideline is:

> Questions are expected to be about Amateur radio specifically, or about the technology of radio. For example, […]